# Difference between load-file and load

Tags: elisp, functions

I went through the documentation of both the function but they don't seem to shed much information. What is the actual difference between them apart from the fact that `load` is a built-in function in C source code whereas load-file is an interactive list compiled function.

What is the recommended function to use in `init.el` since both seem to be doing the same job ?

Comment: What part of [the documentation for this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html#How-Programs-Do-Loading) was not clear in this regard? Consider reporting the doc problem, if you really think there is one: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. As @shosti says, and as the doc clearly indicates, `load-file` "**does not use `load-path`, and does not append suffixes**", for two important differences.

Comment: See also the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are several ways to load Lisp files in Emacs:

1. `load-file` takes a literal filename (relative or absolute) and loads the code. Example: `(load-file "/usr/local/share/site-lisp/foo.el")`
2. `load` is like `load-file`, except that it is more flexible--you can leave out the extension and it will automatically load the "elc" or "el" file as appropriate.
   It also looks into the `load-path` directories.
   Example: `(load "foo")` (if "foo.el" is in the current directory or in the load-path").
3. `load-library` is an interactive interface for `load`.
4. `require` is similar to `load`, except it prevents the file from being loaded more than once (it also requires a corresponding `provide` statement at the end of the file in question). Example: `(require 'foo)`

Comment: Your `require` example is a `load` example. ;-)

Comment: The `load-file` example uses `load`. :)

Comment: Sorry to say 2 and 3 were wrong. :-) `load` _does_ look into the load-path.

Comment: @Malabarba Oops, you're right, thanks for the correction. That is more confusing than I thought.

Answer (score 10):

`load-file` and `load-library` are *commands* for interactive use (where
the main difference is in the initial content of the prompt).

`load` is the underlying *function* to use when you write Elisp (such as
in your .emacs).

Comment: :D  Your answer exactly explains the suggestions in [*The GNU Emacs FAQ*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Evaluating-Emacs-Lisp-code.html): “You can use `M-x` `load-file` to have Emacs evaluate all the Lisp forms in a file. (To do this **from Lisp** use the function `load` **instead**.)”